# HTML5 Drag&Drop: Implementing the whole sequence manually

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I have a complex UI component with custom Drag & Drop behaviour and custom event code of several hundred lines, that basically works via regular `MouseEvent`s.

I need to add additional functionality so that a user can Drag & Drop items from inside the component to outside the component. The "outside" works via regular HTML5 Drag & Drop events, meaning there is an element that already listens to the drop event, etc. Now, i just need to trigger the whole Drag & Drop chain, so that the drop zone element notices the event and during the drag operation i have the regular look drag image.

Simply setting my draggable item to `draggable="true"`, does not work as the dragstart event is not thrown, it is prevented by our custom event code inside the component with `event.preventDefault()`. So my idea was to manually trigger dragstart events whenever the user wants to drag the item outside of the boundary of the component.

My current status is, that my `onMoveStart()` triggers the `dragstart` event, once it realizes the user wants to drag the item outside of the component. The `onMove()` triggers regular `drag` events while moving the mouse, the `onMoveEnd()` triggers the corresponding `dragend` / `drop` events. A somewhat similar and very boiled down version can be seen here: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Mav3N/dv6z7at5/3/).

Problem: A `dragstart` is properly triggered when dragging an item outside of the component, a drag event is properly triggered while regular mouse moving, the dragend event also works. The dropzone element however never receives the drop event. Additionally, there is no dragging image during the drag operation, which makes this look not working to the user. The datatransfer that i manually setup always has `effectAllowed` and `dropOperation` set to `none` even though i manually set them to proper values.

How can i get this working? How to implement the Drag & Drop behaviour manually? How to set the `effectAllowed` and `dropEffect` properties on `DataTransfer` manually so that i have a proper dragging effect without them being always overwritten to `none`?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/Mav3N/dv6z7at5/3/) you provided, I produced something that built around it. From your post and my understanding, I believe there are 2 problems or maybe 3 that you are trying to solve

I start with dragging image. So I just clone the element that we want it to appear as dragging, set it with proper attributes

```
function draggingImage(el) {
  let image = draggable.cloneNode(true);
  image.setAttribute("id", "drag-image");
  image.style.width = el.offsetWidth + 'px'
  image.style.height = el.offsetHeight + 'px'
  image.style.position = 'fixed'
  image.style.left = el.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
  image.style.top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
  image.style.background = getComputedStyle(draggable).backgroundColor
  image.style.opacity = .5
  let div = document.body.appendChild(image);
}
```

as for now, the dragging image is static, as expected, and we want it to move as our mouse move thus the dragging effect

```
  let image = document.getElementById('drag-image')
  image.style.left = image.getBoundingClientRect().left + e.movementX + 'px'
  image.style.top = image.getBoundingClientRect().top + e.movementY + 'px'
```

while our mousemove with wasdragging = true, it's a good time to detect what's underneath our cursor, are we within the dropzone or outside

```
function getDropzone(e, left, top, id) {
  // let rect1 = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
  let rect1 = drop.getBoundingClientRect()
  // to detect the overlap of mouse into the dropzone, as alternative of mouseover
  var overlap = !(rect1.right < left ||
    rect1.left > left ||
    rect1.bottom < top ||
    rect1.top > top)

  return overlap

}
```

we can add the above function within onDrag function. The getDropzone function return true or false, and that's all needed. From there we can execute our logic or styling accordingly.

I also add global variable called as data, then a function that work almost similar to dataTransfer concept, naively.

```
let data = {}

function manualSetData(variable, v) {
  data[variable] = v
}
```

with this, we can just get the data that we set with this function in ondragend

```
let getData = data[variable]
```

so this is DnD from scratch in a nutshell

```js
const draggable = document.querySelector("#draggable");
const drop = document.querySelector("#drop");
const condition = true;
let wasDragging = false;
let allowedDrop = false
let data = {}

draggable.addEventListener("mousedown", onMoveStart)
document.addEventListener("mousemove", onMove)
document.addEventListener("mouseup", onMoveEnd)

function onMoveStart(e) {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  let el = e.target
  // Other logic and custom event handling ...

  if (condition) {
    onDragStart(el);
  }
}

function onMove(e) {
  // Other logic ...
  if (wasDragging) {
    onDrag(e);
  }
}

function onMoveEnd(event) {
  // Other logic ...
  if (wasDragging) {
    onDragEnd(event.target);
  }
}

function onDragStart(el) {
  draggingImage(el)
  wasDragging = true;
  manualSetData('helloMom', el)
}

function draggingImage(el) {
  let image = draggable.cloneNode(true);
  image.setAttribute("id", "drag-image");
  image.style.width = el.offsetWidth + 'px'
  image.style.height = el.offsetHeight + 'px'
  image.style.position = 'fixed'
  image.style.left = el.getBoundingClientRect().left + 'px';
  image.style.top = el.getBoundingClientRect().top + 'px';
  image.style.background = getComputedStyle(draggable).backgroundColor
  image.style.opacity = .5
  let div = document.body.appendChild(image);
}

function manualSetData(variable, v) {
  data[variable] = v
}

function onDrag(e) {
  let image = document.getElementById('drag-image')
  image.style.left = image.getBoundingClientRect().left + e.movementX + 'px'
  image.style.top = image.getBoundingClientRect().top + e.movementY + 'px'

  let left = e.pageX;
  let top = e.pageY;
  let overlap = getDropzone(e, left, top)

  drop.style.backgroundColor = allowedDrop ? 'green' : 'blue'
  if (overlap) {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'copy';
    allowedDrop = true
  } else {
    document.body.style.cursor = 'no-drop';
    allowedDrop = false
  }

}

function getDropzone(e, left, top, id) {
  // let rect1 = document.getElementById(id).getBoundingClientRect();
  let rect1 = drop.getBoundingClientRect()
  // to detect the overlap of mouse into the dropzone, as alternative of mouseover
  var overlap = !(rect1.right < left ||
    rect1.left > left ||
    rect1.bottom < top ||
    rect1.top > top)

  return overlap

}

function onDragEnd(element) {
  let image = document.getElementById('drag-image')
  image.remove()
  document.body.style.cursor = 'default';
  if (allowedDrop) {
    let getData = data['helloMom']
    drop.appendChild(getData)
  }


  wasDragging = false;
}
```

```css
#draggable {
  background-color: red;
}

#drop {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="draggable" draggable="true">
fancy content
</div>

<div id="drop">
drop area
</div>
```